# Regular expression to check if string contains only zeros

Tags: c#, regex

I need to validate an Amount field, which should not be Zero amount. For eg. it **CANNOT** be **0000,0.00,000.000,0** 
BUT it **CAN** be **0.0001, 1.000,1.00,1234.00** etc values.

Tried `@"[^1-9]+"` and `@"0+((\.0+)"` But they invalidate every value which contains a zero.

Comment: Why don't you just convert the string to a number and check if it is 0?

Comment: I presume you are going to need to use the amount afterwards anyway so checking if the number is 0 would be a much better solution.

Comment: Try parsing the string. If parse is successful, multiply it with some number, if you get zero it has zeroes only. Simplest solution ;)

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva - I'm curious, where does the multiplication come into it? Surely to get 0, you would have had a 0 to begin with?

Comment: In the sense of 'because we can', you could do it without parsing or regex, by checking if any char is between 1 and 9 `bool hasnumbers = inputstring.Any(c => c >= '1' && c <= '9');`

Comment: @Sayse m talking about this: http://csharppad.com/gist/4484b970f0ac1401c925

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva - I slightly [modified](http://csharppad.com/gist/7fcb5ee0e72ec95230f2) your example, (ignoring res). Not sure what the purpose of the multiplication is

Comment: @Sayse oh sorry I wrote incorrect code. Instead of multiplying with zero multiply it with some number. Multiplication is done to check if all digits are zeroes or not. Suppose parse results in 0.001 then multiplying it with 2 will get a non-zero number and if its 0.000 it will give 0 as result in multiplication. Yeah you could check with parsing only to. I just wrote what came to my mind first. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don´t see why you need a regex, simply convert the string to a number and check if that is `0`:

```
decimal actNumber;
if(decimal.TryParse(myAmount, out actNumber) && actNumber > 0) 
{ /* ... */ }
```

Thus you can also use the actual number afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a regular expression to check for strings containing only one character, you can just specify that the character be located at the beginning, end, and everywhere in between. Here is an example of how to do so for the digit 0:

`regexp '^0+$'`

If you are worried about the value containing non-zero digits, you can ensure that no such characters are present using:

`regexp '^[^1-9]+$'`

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: I'm not OP but I'd like to say a late thanks, I didn't even think of this. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?=.*?[1-9])\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

You can use a simple `lookahead` for this which will validate if there is at least one `[1-9]`.